# Laravel 5.4 Id Obfuscation jenssegers in Model mutators

Tags: laravel, obfuscation

Id Obfuscation is giving me headache this days. I did manage to use facades in getter but setter it doesn't work specially in the relationship. I have check the relationship without Obfuscating and it works. I think the setter will be applied during form submission only. Here is my code.

```
 public function merchantCategory(){


    return $this->hasMany('App\MerchantCategory', 'maincategory_id', 'id');
}

public function getIdAttribute($value){

    return Obfuscate::encode($value);
}

public function setIdAttribute($value){

  return Obfuscate::decode($value);
}
```

The only problem is the relationship it's because I used the getIdAttribute and it doesn't anymore the original value when doing a relationship. How can I also decode it directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your model, you can set the route key to obfuscate it without having to mess with getters and setters.

```
public function getRouteKey()
{
    return Obfuscate::encode($this->getKey());
}
```

So now when using the `route()` helper, it's exactly the same as when you don't obfuscate.

```
route('route.path', $model)
```

Add a model binding in your `RouteServiceProvider` to finish it off:

```
public function boot()
{
    Router::bind('model', function($value)
    {
        return Model::find(Obfuscate::decode($value));
    });

    parent::boot();
}
```

This way, your relationships are still using a plain ID rather than obfuscating it, and you still get the model binding in your controllers.

```
public function show(Model $model)
{
    return view('model.show', compact('model'));
}
```

Comment: This one would work... I have already messed up my work... hahaha... and created a facade just to let this work. Anyway, thank you so much for this one. I'm going to accept and apply it in my next project. :)

Comment: @Rbex I understand how that goes!